# Wordpress: if category has NO children display single.php else display archive.php

Tags: wordpress, templates, if-statement, parent, categories

As per the title,

I am using a accordion menu that displays my categories and sub categories.

If a category has any children i wish the results to be displayed using my modified archive.php. However if there are no children i wish for the post to be displayed on single.php.

many thanks in advance.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

A while back I wrote a plugin called [Category Template Hierarchy](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-template-hierarchy), it will easily let you accomplish what your trying to do by the fact that it lets you create templates specifically for templates that are parents.

It won't use `archive.php`, but it will allow you to create a template called `parent-category.php`. Anything that is not a parent will be ignored.

Additionally, the plugin gives you access to a conditional tag `is_parent_category()`.